# One Event for all my textBoxes. (VC# Windows Form Application)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've searched a lot on this site and found similar questions but none of the answers could help me. So I'm going to ask myself. I have this code that doesn't work when I want to put all my textBoxes to the same event, here it is:

```
private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
  textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

I made this code by looking at other answers on this site to similar questions.
I also made this one by combining answers I found here on this site:

```
private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
  {
    if (x is TextBox)
     {
      ((TextBox)x).SelectionLength = 0;
     }
  }
}
```

Which also doesn't work...
Can someone please tell me the easiest way to give the same event to all your textBoxes?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  To which control is `OnMouseUp` attached?

Comment: The first one would work.  You need to point the mouse up event on the textbox to this method. Have you done it?

Comment: This code is working what do you expect to happen? This way no user can select a portion of your `TextBox` texts using mouse, however they may do it using keyboard for a while.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. You could manually write your event handler and manually write the event assignment to each textbox (like Niels V answered), you could loop over your form and get all the textboxes and dynamically add the event. You could go to the Designer and click on the control, switch to the Event tab in the properties window and pick your Event from the drop down.

Answer (score 3):

Add `textbox1.OnMouseUp+= OnMouseUp` in your forms class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want *every* `Textbox` on your form to have this event:

```
private void AssignEvent(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{   
    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        if (c is Textbox)
            c.MouseUp += OnMouseUp;

        if (c.HasChildren)
            AssignEvent(c.Controls);
    }
}
```

Call this in your `Form_Load` like so:

```
AssignEvent(this.Controls);
```

This method just loops over every control on your form, and every child control (ie `Form` has a `Groupbox`, `Groupbox` has a `Textbox`). If it's a `Textbox`, it assigns the event. If it's not, it'll simply move on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
        {
            if (x is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)x).MouseUp += SLMethod;
            }
        }
    }

    static void SLMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
```

What this code is doing is making me unable to select the code within my box with my mouse. Which is what I want. 
I did not really understand your answers but thank you anyways!

Comment: What don't you understand? You basically did what I did in my answer, and what Neil's also said in his answer. The problem was the lack of an assignment of the event to the control, which you've fixed with  `someTextbox.MouseUp += SLMethod;`. Each time the `MouseUp` event fires now, it'll call `SLMethod`. Where as in your original post, you never assigned `OnMouseUp` to any of the textboxes, so they had nothing to do when that event fired.

Comment: Also, FYI if you have nested controls (such as a `GroupBox` containing a `Textbox`) as I noted in my answer, your implementation won't assign `SLMethod` to the "inner" `Textbox`.

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant. Thought that with private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) it fired automatically when I let my mouse up on a textBox,

Comment: No, simply by typing up an event doesn't make anything subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If you want to make allt your textbox "unselectable" using a  standard .Net way :

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
    {
        if (x is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)x).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

If it's only to get them unselectable by mouse, then keep the controls attached to your event.